# Is zmq_send() thread safe?

Tags: c++, windows, zeromq

What I mean is can it be called concurrently by multiple threads without eventual negative consequences?

I've read that ZMQ sockets are NOT thread safe. So I wonder maybe it's true also for zmq_send() because it takes zmq socket as one of the parameters?

Answer (score 4):

`zmq_send` is given a socket to send on as one of its arguments.  The thread that calls `zmq_send` **must** be the same thread that created the socket by calling `zmq_socket`.